# Woocommerce separate orders when add to cart is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I put a few custom fields as part of the add to cart form and I'm trying to separate the orders every time the add to cart button is clicked.

Right now when I order an item and fill up the form I get 1 item added to cart and if I fill up the form again with different data and click add to cart the new data gets lost and the count of the first product is increased to 2.

At the same time when viewing the cart page I want to be able to increase the count of separate orders when changing the count and clicking update chart.

What hook can I use to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add fields directly to add to cart form. 
From admin panel make your product variant product. There you can add product variants like color, size etc. You can add your own variations also. This will automatically create extra fields to add to cart field.

Then, your products will be added separately.

Check out the link:
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/variable-product/

Comment: The problem is that I want to personalize the products so I need text fields and file upload.